# Problem in closing audio clip

Tags: java, swing

i use netbeans and i have this code thru which i play an audio clip

now, i want that when the user presses next button on the JFrame. the frame disposes another opens and the clip stops.

here is my code:

this goes in the mose released event of the button:

```
Reg1 ro = new Reg1();
ro.setVisible(true);
clip.close();
this.dispose();
```

this goes in main:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Welcome1 insta = new Welcome1();
                insta.setVisible(true);
                        KeyListener s;

        try {
            AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("x.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audio);
            clip.start();
        }

        catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
            System.out.println(uae);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException lua) {
            System.out.println(lua);
        }

            }
        });
```

it shows an error in the line clip.close();

What shoud I do to remove the error?
Please explain your answer as I am a newbie.

**The error is:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code
        at Welcome1.jButton2MouseReleased(Welcome1.java:60)
        at Welcome1.access$000(Welcome1.java:7)
        at Welcome1$1.mouseReleased(Welcome1.java:29)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:273)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: What is the error

Comment: You forgot to add stacktrace of exception.

Comment: sorry but i dont know what stack trace is

Comment: @Karan: what you have posted as an error is called stacktrace of execption.

Comment: then there is no error only this stacktrace of exception. Also, what should i do to resolute the scope of clip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i needed to do was initialise the variables under the class, rather that under main... as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the `Clip` instance is out of scope at the time the code calls `Clip.close()`.

That is only a guess because it is hard to say much with code snippets, the line numbers of a stack trace are unable to indicate exact code lines.  Please consider posting an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) in future.